# instance of a failable init method

Tags: swift, binding, conditional-statements, option-type, initializer

This is my code:

```
struct Book{
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let price: String?
    let pubDate: String?

init?(title: String, author: String, price: String, pubDate: String){
    guard let title = title, let author = author else { // error here
        return nil
    }

    self.title = title
    self.author = author
    self.price = price
    self.pubDate = pubDate
}
```

}

My error says Initializer for conditional binding must have Option type not 'String'
My question is, why do I get this error, if I understand the guard statement correctly, I should only pass in the non-Optional properties before the else, and after the braces, the optional ones, like I've done here.

Comment: Your `init?` method does not take any optional arguments. – Perhaps you meant `init?(title: String?, author: String?, ...)` ?

Comment: only price and pubDate are optionals in my struct though. 
Adding `price: String?, pubDate: String?) {...`didn't fix my error however.

Comment: I'm confused – under what circumstances should your initialiser fail? You cannot use `if let` or `guard let` with non-optionals.

Comment: @JakobHansen: the `title` and `author` parameter of `init?` are **not** optionals, therefore `guard let title = title` does not compile. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: If I don't initialize price or pubDate on one instance, I would still like for it to run

Comment: @MartinR I expected the price: String? and pubDate: String?  to be optional, so that on some instances, those properties may be nil.

Comment: And what is the guard statement for? When do you want your init method to *fail?*

Comment: I assumed that I had to use a guard statement to unwrap the 2 optionals ( price and pubDate) 

I would like my init method to fail, if one of those two optionals are empty / nil. 

I'd like to be able to create an instance of book like this:

let someBook = Book(title: "Harry potter","author: George Lucas","pubDate":"1996")

Comment: You are contradicting yourself: Above you said *"If I don't initialize price or pubDate on one instance, I would still like for it to run"* and now you say *"I would like my init method to fail, if one of those two optionals are empty / nil."* – Perhaps I am misunderstanding you. Please add examples **to your question** of init calls that should fail, and examples of init calls that should succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you forego the *failable init* altogether.  Your structure holds a `title` and `author` which are not *Optional*, so make your initializer reflect that.  Don't let them try to create a book unless they can provide a title and and author.

The other two properties are *Optional*.  I suggest you provide default values of `nil` in the initializer for those, which gives your user the most flexibility in creating a `Book`:

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let price: String?
    let pubDate: String?

    init(title: String, author: String, price: String? = nil, pubDate: String? = nil) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.price = price
        self.pubDate = pubDate
    }
}

let book1 = Book(title: "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", author: "Douglas Adams")
let book2 = Book(title: "The Shining", author: "Stephen King", price: "20.00")
let book3 = Book(title: "Little Women", author: "Louisa May Alcott", price: "15.99", pubDate: "1868")
let book4 = Book(title: "Harry Potter", author: "J. K. Rowling", pubDate: "1997")
```

---

If you really want to be able to pass in `nil` for anything, but fail if they don't provide a `title` and an `author`, then use `guard` to unwrap `title` and `author`, otherwise fail and return `nil`:

```
init?(title: String? = nil, author: String? = nil, price: String? = nil, pubDate: String? = nil) {
    guard let title = title, author = author else { return nil }
    self.title = title
    self.author = author
    self.price = price
    self.pubDate = pubDate
}

// These all return nil
let book5 = Book()
let book6 = Book(title: "War and Peace")
let book7 = Book(author: "Ray Bradbury")
let book8 = Book(title: "Pride and Prejudice", price: "40.00", pubDate: "1813")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use guard for only optional variables to unwrap expected data or early fail to return from function or loops.Also you don't need to make all parameters optional.There is also other reasons can cause initialization fail.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let price: String?
    let pubDate: String?

    init?(dict: [String : String]){
        guard let title = dict["title"], let author = dict["author"] else {
            return nil
        }
        let price = dict["price"]
        let pubDate = dict["pubDate"]

        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.price = price
        self.pubDate = pubDate
    }
}
```